# Is there any way i can web-scrape my browser homepage?

Tags: python, web-scraping

i want to create a python app where i can get data from my browser homepage (in this case Brave Browser). How can i do this without a url?

[image]

Comment: There is absolutely nothing you can do without knowing the page source, and usually that's a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not think this is possible. For web scraping, you might use `requests` or `urllib` to download the page then use an HTML parser, such as `BeautifulSoup4` or `lxml`, to scrape the webpage. While browsers may have a URL for the new tab (Chrome, for example, has *chrome://newtab*), `requests` and `urllib` aren't able to establish connections to the URLs.

For `requests`:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> res = requests.get("chrome://newtab")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    res = requests.get("chrome://newtab")
  ...
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'chrome://newtab'
```

For `urllib`:

```py
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> res = urlopen("chrome://newtab")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    res = urlopen("chrome://newtab")
  File "C:\Users\JLpyt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  ...
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: chrome>
```

With browser automation packages (`selenium`, `playwright`, `pyppeteer`), you *are* able to access the new tab page, by sending the **Ctrl+T**/**Cmd+T** virtual keystrokes. From there, you would be able to pass the page content to an HTML parser and scrape the page. While this is possible for 'classic' browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, etc.), I don't know of any package for Brave Browser.

Perhaps there is something I am missing, but, as far as I know, you cannot scrape the new tab page of Brave Browser.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I may have been a bit confusing in my explanation, but I just wanted to mention that the new tab pages cannot be scraped using the URL, if there is one. For the browsers I listed in my answer, you could use, say `selenium`, launch a new session, navigate to a webpage, then send the **Ctrl+T** keys to open a new tab. From there you would be able to pass the page HTML to an HTML parser, `BeautifulSoup4` for example, to scrape the page. Since Brave Browser is not supported by any browser automation package that I know of, there isn't a way to scrape the home page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now everything is clear <3